# Detect more than 1 modifier keys (ctrl & alt) not combined

Tags: vb.net, keypress, alt, ctrl, modifier-key

How to detect more than 1 moddifier keys? (`Alt` & `Ctrl`)?

I have this working code:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseWheel
    If ModifierKeys = Keys.Control Then
        If e.Delta <> 0 Then
            PictureBox1.Width += CInt(PictureBox1.Width * e.Delta / 1000)
            PictureBox1.Height += CInt(PictureBox1.Height * e.Delta / 1000)
        end if
     end if
end sub
```

if i change it into:
`If ModifierKeys = (Keys.Control Or Keys.Alt) Then` 
stop working.
How can i detect both keys, but not combined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If ModifierKeys = Keys.Control OrElse ModifierKeys = Keys.Alt Then
```

That really should have been obvious.